# Default config for .NET 5 code style analyzers

Tags: .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, .net-5

In .NET 5 there are two kinds of analyzers: code quality and code style. They are specified in `.editorconfig`.

Specifying each rule by hand would take forever so it's useful to rely on Microsoft official "defaults".

For **code quality rules**, there are [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/predefined-configurations#predefined-editorconfig-files) defaults, [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers).

For **code style rules**, I haven't found official defaults. There are various examples in various places, but nothing that seems "official". I realize I can just enable/disable all of them as a one-liner, but I want finer control than that (exactly like I do for code quality rules).

Can someone point me to an official/default editorconfig for code style rules?

Comment: There aren't any *default* code quality rules. The link you posted talks about predefined code quality rules for a *specific analyzer*. You can use whatever defaults you want for your. own analyzers.  All rules are configured through `editorconfig`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes those are defaults for the code quality rules shipped in the framework. I was wondering if the same existed for the code style rules that are shipped in the framework. I suppose not, thanks for confirming.

Comment: I suppose a workaround is to set everything to warning, in a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49250#issuecomment-760387102) they're adding default / recommended code style rule config in the .NET 6 SDK.

Until then there's no recommended code style. Every Microsoft repo uses different code styles.

Wish there were a standard, like go's `gofmt`.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://msbuildlog.com/ to look at what being setup in your project.

If you right click on the project and select **Preprocess**, you'll get a MSBuild file that has everything that contributes to the build.

On the SDK ("C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\build" and "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\build\config") or on the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers) package there are editorconfig files that you can import that have everything set as warning.

But setting `AnalysisLevel` should take care of it.

[Overview of .NET source code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview)

Comment: That's for code quality rules, not the code style rules. Seems like they're gonna add that in the next SDK (See my answer below). Thanks for the link to msbuildlog it looks very useful!